# How to prevent Docker from looking up host names via external DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, docker

Say you have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    expose:
      - 80

  # Imaginary service that requests http://web/
  curl:
    image: curlimages/curl
    command: curl -i http://web/
```

If `web` is down, accessing `http://web/` will trigger an external DNS lookup. In my case, this caused several hundred thousand requests per hour to our DNS server.

How can I prevent Docker from externally looking up host names when a container is down?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I block Docker from trying to resolve external DNS names?](https://serverfault.com/questions/993349/how-can-i-block-docker-from-trying-to-resolve-external-dns-names)

Comment: I believe this has been answered in this [Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/993349/how-can-i-block-docker-from-trying-to-resolve-external-dns-names)

Comment: @HenrikPingel I don't want to block Docker from resolving DNS names nor do I want a dummy DNS service. I just want to prevent Docker from trying to externally resolve names of containers that are down. It's also ok if I can exclude such names explicitly.

Comment: @michel I am facing the same problem. Could you find a solution? My solution is to add all service names to the local /etc/hosts files on any server the service could be startet, but it is a pain in the ass with hunderts of services and servers.